# Javascript Mask not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, mobile

> *I don't have a perfect english, sorry for any mistake...*

I use a JS telephone/cell phone mask code that I've fount at Internet, it works fine when I access my website using my computer, but when I use my phone, the code stop working.

**Here's the JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mascara(o, f) {
        v_obj = o
        v_fun = f
        setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
    }
    function execmascara() {
        v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
    }
    function mtel(v) {
        v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
        v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g, "($1)$2");
        v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/, "$1-$2");
        return v;
    }
    function id(el) {
        return document.getElementById(el);
    }
    window.onload = function () {

        id('<%= telefoneContato.ClientID %>').onkeypress = function () {
            mascara(this, mtel);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**This is the text field:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="telefoneContato" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu telefone" MaxLength="14"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Some points:**

- I'm using bootstrap + jQuery;
- The page is a webform and it's linked to a MasterPage;
- I'm using ASP.NET;
- I don't have much experience with JS;
- The phone is a Moto G4 (Android 6.0.1) and I used chrome to access the website.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, behavior of the key events differs on each browser and especially when it comes to mobile browsers it can be so annoying. Try using a mobile compatible jQuery library such as [jQuery Mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). You will be able to define your masks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.phone').mask('0000-0000');
});
```